# Facebook iOS SDK not calling completion handler when authorized app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

I call doFacebookLogin my app switches to facebook to authorize the app but after I allow the app to access my information and switches back.

Nothing happen. No "complete" in console.

If I call doFacebookLogin again the console shows

```
complete
Session state closed
```

Here is my code.

```
- (void)doFacebookLogin:(id)sender
{
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"complete");
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Session state changed");
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        NSLog(@"Session state open");
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if(error == nil) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [user debugDescription]);
            }
        }];
        break;

    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        NSLog(@"Session state closed");
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if(error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}    
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have this in AppDelegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url

if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"fb"]) {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
.....
```

And also you need to check if your app has Url Types section for facebook in AppName-info.plist